# Shrink/flatten tool - unstable increase/decrease of size of selected faces (fluctuating)

Tags: objects, edit-mode

The shrink/flatten tool in edit mode tends to increase/decrease in a fluctuating way,on moving the mouse slightly, it changes to a very large one in an instant, wont decrease below that base size. I've tried to decrease my mouse sensitivity, changed the mouse, still won't go.

Comment: 10 to 1 you’ve got Snap To Vertex turned on. Check the magnet at the top of the 3D view.

Comment: And the shortcut is Shift+Tab